# Check if a given ID exists using Stored Procedure by If Exists or If Not Exists?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using stored procedures for insert, update, delete operations in database. To check if a given `ID` exists, I use if exists condition in my code. Here's my issue: I am given the `ID` which is in database, but the condition checks and allows duplicate values to be stored in database.

My stored procedure code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

If @Action = 'Insert'   --used to Insert records
Begin
    If Exists(select BatchNo from Work_In_Progress where BatchNo = '@BatchNo')
    Begin
        set @Error='Already Exists'     
    End     
    Else 
    Begin                  
        insert into Work_In_Progress 
        values (@BatchNo, @ISR_No, @CatalogNo, @Brandname, @Productname, @Operation_Code, @Operation_Name, @Machine_Id, @Received_Qty, @Finished_Qty, @Balance_Qty, @Accepted_Qty, @Rejected_Qty, @Startdate, @Starttime, @Enddate, @Endtime, @Accp_MTS_No, @Rej_MTS_No, @Remarks, @Work_Done_By, @Approved_By, @Updated_Date, @Updated_By, @InspectionStatus);

        insert into Sample_Inspection   
        values(@BatchNo,@Operation_Code,@Inspection_Name,@Insp_Parameter,@Insp_Tolerance,@Observation,@Sample_Rcd_Qty,@Sample_Accepted_Qty,@Sample_Rejected_Qty,@Sample_Rework_Qty,@Sample_Accp_MTS_No,@Sample_Rej_MTS_No,@Sample_Rework_MTS_No,@Sample_Remarks,@Sample_WorkDone_By,@Sample_WorkDone_Date,@Sample_Approved_By,@Sample_Updated_Date,@Sample_Updated_By);
   End
End
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Make sure your "select BatchNo from Work_In_Progress where BatchNo=@BatchNo" returns null.. @BatchNo That Parameter doesnt need Quotes..

Comment: pass @BatchNo parameter directly. single quote is not required otherwise it will search for "@BatchNo" in field which never exists. If Exists(select BatchNo from Work_In_Progress where BatchNo=@BatchNo)

Comment: You're comparing BatchNo to the string '@BatchNo', not the variable...

Comment: Yes,I am comparing the BatchNo which is a string in DB to insert.

Comment: You're not getting it. You're comparing `BatchNo`, in your table, with `'@BatchNo'`, a literal string. Not `@BatchNo` the variable. Note the single quotes. Just remove the single quotes. No single quotes. Just `where BatchNo = @BatchNo`.

Comment: Yes,you are right Steen.It works in my code.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it without the quotes around `@BatchNo`:

```
If Exists(select BatchNo from Work_In_Progress where BatchNo = @BatchNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @id int =null,
@ret int=null
if Not exists(select id from table1 where id=@id)
begin
 --insert query,
     --set  @ret=@id
     end
      else 
   begin
    ---set  @ret=-1
    end
```

Comment: I merely removed the text that added no value to your answer. Politeness and niceties are considered noise and are unnecessary. A correct answer is more worth than signatures or greetings.